# Choice of Primary Key and unexpected behaviour of Auto Increment in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, auto-increment

Hi I'm making an event management site. The users (each having a unique login id) from all over the world can add events.  The events are stored in a temporary table and when approved by admin are transferred to the events table.

I need to choose a very efficient key for event_id. Surrogate key will be the best option. Currently I'm using Auto Increment.

1) Does the auto increment consider the last largest primary key present in the table or the last key added.

Issue)  Event id 41, 42, 43 present in temporary table. Admin approves event_id 43 and it leaves the temp table. The largest key in temp table now is 42.

next event added is again alloted id 43 in the temp table. Why is this happening ?

I want to use something else as primary key. What should I do ??    is timestamp+userid a good option. this will result in a very long Primary key though

Answer (score 1):

The auto increment values come from a counter, so usually you won't get a value twice. Also, every table gets a counter of its own.

There's a catch with the InnoDB storage engine though: the counter is reset to the maximum value of the column on server startup, so you may get 43 again if MySQL is restarted between the delete and the insert. If you use the MyISAM storage engine, this won't happen because the counter is stored on disk.

For scalability some people recommend using UUIDs because they enable you to divide the db between several servers, without fear of accidental reuse of the primary key somewhere. UUID keys however need more CPU and storage.

Comment: Thanks. SO any suggestion what should I use.??

Comment: Just use auto increment, how likely are you going to ever need more than one server for the event database?

Comment: We'll be using a single server only.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely Right. I added three events( 1,2,3) to the temporary table. I approved events(1,2).  Restarted the server. Next event added was given event_id 2.   Never knew this. It really poses serious threats. Thank god i tested this carefully. Yes i'm using innoDB. I don;t have reputation enough to vote u. I'll do as soon as I get reputation.

Comment: Joni Thanks A lot. Using Myisam. no probs .Things running smooth.